# How do I get all objects that are more than a day old in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a query in Django for posts older than 24 hours. The Post form contains a DateTime field named Created_at and this field contains the time the post was added.

How do I get all posts older than 24 hours in Django?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can retrieve the objects with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Post.objects.filter(Created_at__lte=Now()-timedelta(hours=24))
```

Comment: `timedelta(days=1)` would be too obvious, eh?

Comment: @RichardNeumann: no, but it says "older than 24 hours", so it is a *literal* translation :)

Comment: @RichardNeumann: yes, but "older than a day" is a bit ambiguous, since it can mean "yesterday" or "24 hours". Therefore this is less ambiguous. While `days=1` for a timedelta is indeed 24 hours, it can create confusion.

Comment: What is "Created_at__lte"?

Comment: @C132: `Created_at` is the name of the field, and the `__lte` is a lookup for less than or equal https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lte

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem any benefit over functions.Now() over datetime.now()?

Comment: @MedunoyeLaxusGbenga: two: it works with the database datetime which is also the one that assigns timestamps, so might be slightly better for timedelta, and (b) you can use this as `queryset = ` in a CBV for example, so no need to override `get_queryset` and each time construct a new queryset. `Now()` does *not* resolve instantly to a datetime, it acts as some sort of token for the database time at the moment of querying

Comment: @MedunoyeLaxusGbenga: using `datetime.now()` is also not a good idea, because it is not timezone sensitive. Django has a `from django.utils.timezone import now` although `Now` is probably better than `now` :).